# CSS Background Shorthand property not work?

Tags: html, css

Why does my CSS background shorthand property not work? I have applied many processes, but it's not working.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 800px;
  height: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: solid 2px;
  background: red url(image/computer.png) no-repeat cover fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
</div>
```

Comment: the below answer is not accurate, you don't need quotes and you can keep "cover" inside background BUT you need to also specify the position (ex: `center / cover` )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems you have to fixed:

You doesn't have the `""` for the url.

You have to separately set the `background-size:cover` property.

Set it in the `background` will not work.

*Not sure if `image/computer.png` is a local image or an invalid image. If it is a local image, just replace the url back (I change the url to wikipedia icon for showing purpose)

```css
*{
         padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        .container{
            width: 800px;
            height: 800px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            border: solid 2px;
            background: red url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/80/Wikipedia-logo-v2.svg/2244px-Wikipedia-logo-v2.svg.png")  0 0 no-repeat fixed;
           
        }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    
        </div>
```

Comment: it's work fine.but sir when i use this property in one line. it's does not work .what  are  the actual problem .can  you explain? i want to use this property in one line.

Comment: @DIPKRGUCHAIT, it is because you doesn't specify the background-position property in the background shorthand. I updated the code where I specify the background position in the background shorthand.